# Add to cart button Yii2

Tags: php, sql, yii2

I want to make a button that when it's pressed insert data into table name 'cart'
This is my button in index

```
'cart' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
                        $modelId = $model->id;
                        return Html::button('<i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>',
                            [
                                'class' => 'btn btn-xs btn-outline-success',
                                'style' => 'width:80px; margin-top: 5px',
                                'data-toggle' => 'tooltip',
                                'title' => Yii::t('app', 'Cart'),
                                'onClick' => 'addProduct('. "{$modelId}" . ');'
                            ]);
                    },
```

And this is my function

```
public function addProduct($id)
{
    $product = Product::find()->where(['id' => $id])->one();
    if (isset($product)) {
        Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->insert("cart", [
            "product_id" => $product->id,
            "name" => $product->name,
            "price" => $product->price,
            "image" => $product->image,
        ])->execute();
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Item added successfully');
    }
}
```

And I have this error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: addProduct is not defined
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: Where is ajax call to action? `addProduct()` should be defined in JS if you want to use it onclick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

comment need 50 reputation, so I send answer.

if `public function addProduct` is a PHP function,

on click event is javascript event, maybe you must write a js function in page?

like there:

```
$this->registerJs(
    "$('#myButton').on('click', function() { alert('Button clicked!'); });",
    View::POS_READY,
    'my-button-handler'
);
```

the `function() { alert('Button clicked!'); });` is js function.([Registering inline scripts](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-client-scripts))